# Как получить массив в запросе GET используя Request.Query?

Tags: asp.net-core

Доброго времени суток. 
Использую ASP .NET Core.
Подскажите, как можно получить массив в контроллере из запроса GET используя Request.Query?
к примеру вот такие данные:

http://localhost:3140/Home/UpdateRows**?uids[]=d0c9616a-cd48-4d6d-86cd-c2aa0c4caa9b&uids[]=675aa0ba-4865-4b6d-87d8-2eb89a6016e2&uids[]=81e02a62-86b1-4b10-a7fb-a622b04f1cb6**

Конечно данные можно получать и так:

```
string uid = Request.Query.FirstOrDefault( p => p.Key == "uids[]" ).Value;
```

Но получается строка разделенная запятыми, а мне хотелось бы сразу получить массив, что бы мне `uid.Split(',')` не делать.

Можно же получить массив таким образом?:

```
public string Sum(int[] nums)
{
    return $"Сумма чисел равна {nums.Sum()}";
}
```

Используя такой запрос:
http://localhost:57086/Home/Sum**?nums=1&nums=2&nums=3.**

Но как сделать в моем случае, я не понимаю...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Привязка данных в контроллере описана в [официальной документации](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/mvc/models/model-binding). В Вашем конкретном примере можно указать источник привязки модели так:

```
public IActionResult UpdateRows([FromQuery] Guid[] uids){
    // какие-то действия с uids
}
```